# C List of structs from file

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a text file with an easy structure:

```
Foo Bar C
Joe Bob A
.....
```

And I would like to read the file and populate a "matrix" of structs, let's say a list of pointers to that structs.
I have tried:

```
typedef struct Test
{
    char *A;
    char *B;
    char Res;
}Test;

int main()
{
    
    FILE *fptr;
    int i;
    char A[10], B[10], res;
    
    Test **data = malloc(5*sizeof(Test);
     
    // allocate mem for each Struct
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        data[i] = malloc(sizeof(Test));
    }


    fptr = fopen("dati.txt", "r");
    
    // let's say we have 5 records
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {

        fscanf(fptr,"%s %s %c\n", &A, &B, &res);
        
        data[i]->A = A;
        data[i]->B = B;
        data[i]->Res = res;
        
        printf("\A: %s, B: - %s --> %d", data[i]->A, data[i]->B, data[i]->Res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But if I try to read with a for, I can't read the correct values.
What I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: `data[i]->A = A;` will cause each iteration to overwrite previous data, you will only see last read values, same with other params

Comment: I don't see this any way its a valid structure `Foo Bar C`

Answer (score 1):

Your `data[i]->A = A;` are pointers. When you assign `A` to it, you assign the pointer, whose data is overwritten each time you read a record from the file.

You must allocate memory for the data read and then copy the data to the new memory, for example:

```
data[i]->A = malloc(strlen(A)+1);
strcpy(data[i]->A,A);
```